# SSH in Windows console: wrong interpretation of some characters sometimes

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, ssh, console

I use ssh.exe from the MinGW project to access Linux servers from the Windows native commandline. Or I use Console2, a wrapper around cmd.exe which makes it more usable, but it is still cmd.exe in the background.

Generally it works well, but from time to time it has severe problems with interpretation of some characters (mainly CR and LF and other whitespace), which results in weird graphical artifacts. Also when I delete characters using Backspace.

The following image shows an almost correctly displayed session. Just the command prompt shows some leftover characters (in fact, it should display an empty command line).

[image: notice the command prompt with artifacts from previous screen]

In the last image, you can see what Vim looks like when I paste this text:

```
    /brake /cmd_vel /currents /diagnostics /diagnostics_agg /diagnostics_toplevel_state
    /enable /filtered_joint_states /fix /fix_extended
    /flipper_cmd /flippers_cmd /flippers_state /icp_odom /imu/data /imu_odom /visual_odom
    /initialpose /joint_states /laser_center /local_joy/cmd_vel /local_joy/joy
    /magnetic /mechanization_output_inso /mechanization_output_inso_aiddebug
    /mux_cmd_vel/selected /nav/cmd_vel /nifti_robot_node/max_angular_speed /nifti_robot_node/max_linear_speed
    /odom /pointcloud_control /poseupdate /posture /posture_cmd /private/nav/cmd_vel
    /restart3d /robot_status /rosout /rosout_agg /scan /scanning_once /scanning_speed_cmd
    /set_flippers_torque /steering_efficiency
    /syscommand /teleop_joy/cmd_vel /teleop_ocu/cmd_vel /temperature /tf /tf_static /tracks_vel /tracks_vel_cmd /velocity
```

[image: a plain instance of Vim after pasting a few lines of text]

When I (blindly) `:wq` the file and reload it, the text is apparently saved, and then also displayed, correctly. So it's just a visualization problem on the Windows side; the Linux side receives correct input.

When I issue the `clear` command, the window gets always cleared correctly.

What can I do to get rid of this incompatibility? Is there some hidden Windows console setting that would allow me for better compatibility?

(I know Putty handles this well, but I'd like to use ssh in my native commandline)

Comment: These ssh bugs have to be reported to their authors.

Comment: And are they really ssh bugs? Isn't it more a bug in the Windows console, or just a misunderstanding in the used communication protocols?